# Background settings for tiling and stretching seems to be missing in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, desktop-background, system-settings

I'm running Ubuntu with a custom gnome-session which replaces the default window manager with xmonad. I.e., when I log in, I select "Xsession" in lightdm, and I have an `.xsession` file in my home directory which executes `gnome-session --session=xmonad`, where `/usr/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session` contains a modified gnome session which selects xmonad as the window manager. After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, the settings for specifying whether my desktop background/wallpaper should stretch or tile seems to have been removed! There is now just a single, large button for changing the wallpaper, but nothing else.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you cannot change these options for the default Wallpapers, only. If you select your Pictures folder and select an image from there, the options are shown. No?

Comment: Nope, Pictures folder does not have these options either. This is a screenshot of what I get: http://snag.gy/j0vej.jpg

Comment: Well, you don't seem to be using the defaults (something that you didn't mention on your question). This is what I get with the default settings program: http://i.imgur.com/yPSmVuZ.png

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! I actually run xmonad through gnome-session (using a custom gnome session file), so I thought that wouldn't make a difference. However, the system settings window is not the same when running a default session. I managed to fix it by adding the line "DesktopName=Unity" to my custom session file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :). Please make an answer if you want the credit ;)

Comment: You found the answer yourself, actually. Edit your question to add the extra information about your desktop environment and make an answer yourself describing what you did to solve your problem. Next mark your answer as the one solving your question.

Comment: Will do! However, since I just created my account, I cannot answer it yet (must wait 8 hours). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the "system settings" window seems to depend on the *name* of the desktop environment, where the default GNOME desktop environment seems to have been dumbed down such that one cannot configure the tiling mode of the wallpaper. To get that functionality back, add the following line to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session`:

```
DesktopName=Unity
```

For reference, the full session file then looks as follows:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=xmonad
DefaultProvider-panel=lxpanel
DefaultProvider-filemanager=/bin/true
DesktopName=Unity
```

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is in System Settings>Appearance

Next select the option circled below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem for default GNOME, here is a non shell solution from GNOME, from market install gnome tweaks, ref. - [more info](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377329)

P.S. Not to mention that apparently this official program is useful for so many other tweaks in your UI like showing date as well in top bar.